# Where are .gemspecs located?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rapidfire-gem

Where do you find a .gemspec file related to a gem?

For example; Rapidfire for implementation of another gem into its engine?

Where are these .gemspec files located because I can't for the life of me find it and I've checked every folder associated with Rapidfire

```
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.add_dependency "devise"
end
```

Where do I add this to make Devise work in Rapidfire?

Answer (score 1):

`.gemspec` files are located in the root of the repo. For example, [here](https://github.com/code-mancers/rapidfire) you can find the [rapidfire.gemspec](https://github.com/code-mancers/rapidfire/blob/master/rapidfire.gemspec)

Then the gem is packaged, the spec is serialized into a Ruby structured and stored in the `metadata` file within the gem.

If you download a gem, and rename the file from `.gem` to `.zip` (a `.gem` is essentially a zip file) you can explore its content. You'll find a `metadata.gz` file that is a compressed file, that stores the `.gemspec` data.

```
--- !ruby/object:Gem::Specification
name: rapidfire
version: !ruby/object:Gem::Version
  version: 2.1.0
platform: ruby
authors:
- Yuva Kumar
autorequire: 
bindir: bin
cert_chain: []
date: 2015-02-19 00:00:00.000000000 Z
...
```

Comment: I see, that makes sense. So if I have the gem already installed, what would be the best course of action to edit the .gemspec file?